# Fetching Tweets with Swift IOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, twitter

I'm practicing on a sample application that has a social feed page. I'm trying to display each tweet with the corresponding media. I was able to get the text and media but not as one tweet and the further I could get is displaying the media link. Any help on how to get the tweet with the media displayed would be appreciated. To make it clearer the user should be able to view the text and any picture/video from the application without the need to open any links.

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController, 
 UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

//importing objects
@IBOutlet weak var mytextfield: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var myimageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var myTableview: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var myScroll: UIScrollView!
var tweets:[String] = []

//Activity Indicator
var activityInd = UIActivityIndicatorView()

func startA()
{
    UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()
    activityInd.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.gray
    activityInd.center = view.center
    activityInd.startAnimating()
    view.addSubview(activityInd)
}


//setting table view
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tweets.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell
    cell.mytextview.text = tweets[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}



@IBAction func mysearchbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if mytextfield.text != ""
    {
        startA()
        let user = mytextfield.text?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
        getStuff(user: user!)
    }


}


//Create a function that gets all the stuff
func getStuff(user:String)
{
    let url = URL(string: "https://twitter.com/" + user)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data,response, error) in
        if error != nil
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    if let errorMessage = error?.localizedDescription
                    {
                        self.myLabel.text = errorMessage
                    }else{
                        self.myLabel.text = "There has been an error try again"
                    }
            }

        }else{
            let webContent:String = String(data: data!,encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!

            if webContent.contains("<title>") && webContent.contains("data-resolved-url-large=\"")
            {
                //get user name
                var array:[String] = webContent.components(separatedBy: "<title>")
                array = array[1].components(separatedBy: " |")
                let name = array[0]
                array.removeAll()

                //getprofile pic
                array = webContent.components(separatedBy: "data-resolved-url-large=\"")
                array = array[1].components(separatedBy: "\"")
                let profilePic = array[0]
                print(profilePic)

                //get tweets
               array = webContent.components(separatedBy: "data-aria-label-part=\"0\">")
              //get tweets media
                // array = webContent.components(separatedBy: "data-pre-embedded=\"true\" dir=\"ltr\" >")
                array.remove(at: 0)

                for i in 0...array.count-1
                {
                    let newTweet = array[i].components(separatedBy: "<")
                    array[i] = newTweet[0]
                }

                self.tweets = array

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myLabel.text = name
                    self.updateImage(url: profilePic)
                    self.myTableview.reloadData()
                    self.activityInd.stopAnimating()
                    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                }
            }else{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.myLabel.text = "User not found"
                    self.activityInd.stopAnimating()
                    UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
                }
            }
        }
    }
 task.resume()
}


//Function that gets profile pic data
func updateImage(url:String)
{
    let url = URL(string: url)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data, response, error) in 
        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            self.myimageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    myScroll.contentSize.height = 1000
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Okay. Do not parse yourself the html page. Use the WebAPI, there is also a great SDK.framework for iOS: https://dev.twitter.com/twitterkit/ios/overview

Answer (score 1):

**@SYou can use TwitterKit SDK in iOS for your App. Twitter SDK is is fully capable to fulfil your needs. Whatever feed functionality you want you just need to configure it in twitter kit.**

When showing Tweets you can implement these features for your feed :

The style (dark or light)
Colors (text, links, background)
Action Buttons
The delegate (TWTRTweetViewDelegate) to be notified of user interaction with the Tweet

To Show tweets you can do this :

For showing tweets you have two options  :

- You can load any public tweets  (Attention : For Showing Public Tweets You need Public Tweet IDs)

**Swift 4**

For e.g

```
//
//  PublicTweets.swift
//  TwitterFeedDemo
//
//  Created by User on 21/12/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Test Pvt. Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import TwitterKit

class PublicTweets : UITableViewController {

    // setup a 'container' for Tweets
    var tweets: [TWTRTweet] = [] {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    var prototypeCell: TWTRTweetTableViewCell?

    let tweetTableCellReuseIdentifier = "TweetCell"

    var isLoadingTweets = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let user = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID {
            Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.logOutUserID(user)
        }

        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

        // Create a single prototype cell for height calculations.
        self.prototypeCell = TWTRTweetTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: tweetTableCellReuseIdentifier)

        // Register the identifier for TWTRTweetTableViewCell.
        self.tableView.register(TWTRTweetTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: tweetTableCellReuseIdentifier)

        // Setup table data
        loadTweets()
    }

    func loadTweets() {
        // Do not trigger another request if one is already in progress.
        if self.isLoadingTweets {
            return
        }
        self.isLoadingTweets = true

        // set tweetIds to find
        let tweetIDs = ["944116014828138496","943585637881352192","943840936135741440"];

        // Find the tweets with the tweetIDs
        let client = TWTRAPIClient()
        client.loadTweets(withIDs: tweetIDs) { (twttrs, error) -> Void in

            // If there are tweets do something magical
            if ((twttrs) != nil) {

                // Loop through tweets and do something
                for i in twttrs! {
                    // Append the Tweet to the Tweets to display in the table view.
                    self.tweets.append(i as TWTRTweet)
                }
            } else {
                print(error as Any)
            }
        }
    }

}

 // MARK
 // MARK: UITableViewDataSource UITableViewDelegate

extension PublicTweets {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of Tweets.
        return tweets.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // Retrieve the Tweet cell.
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: tweetTableCellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TWTRTweetTableViewCell

        // Assign the delegate to control events on Tweets.
        cell.tweetView.delegate = self
        cell.tweetView.showActionButtons = true

        // Retrieve the Tweet model from loaded Tweets.
        let tweet = tweets[indexPath.row]

        // Configure the cell with the Tweet.
        cell.configure(with: tweet)

        // Return the Tweet cell.
        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        let tweet = self.tweets[indexPath.row]
        self.prototypeCell?.configure(with: tweet)

        return TWTRTweetTableViewCell.height(for: tweet, style: TWTRTweetViewStyle.compact, width: self.view.bounds.width , showingActions:true)
    }
}

extension PublicTweets : TWTRTweetViewDelegate  {
    //Handle Following Events As Per Your Needs
    func tweetView(_ tweetView: TWTRTweetView, didTap url: URL) {

    }

    func tweetView(_ tweetView: TWTRTweetView, didTapVideoWith videoURL: URL) {

    }

    func tweetView(_ tweetView: TWTRTweetView, didTap image: UIImage, with imageURL: URL) {

    }

    func tweetView(_ tweetView: TWTRTweetView, didTap tweet: TWTRTweet) {

    }

    func tweetView(_ tweetView: TWTRTweetView, didTapProfileImageFor user: TWTRUser) {

    }

    func tweetView(_ tweetView: TWTRTweetView, didChange newState: TWTRVideoPlaybackState) {

    }

}
```

- You can also show other users tweets by just having their ScreenName or Twitter UserID

For e.g.

```
//
//  SelfTweets.swift
//  TwitterFeedDemo
//
//  Created by User on 21/12/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Test Pvt. Ltd. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import TwitterKit

class SelfTweets: TWTRTimelineViewController  {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        if let user = Twitter.sharedInstance().sessionStore.session()?.userID {
            let client = TWTRAPIClient()
            self.dataSource = TWTRUserTimelineDataSource.init(screenName:"li_ios", userID: user, apiClient: client, maxTweetsPerRequest: 10, includeReplies: true, includeRetweets: false)
        }
    }

}
```